# UIButton text not displaying

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` on table cell. I am trying to set its text but it is not displaying it.

```
UIButton *btnName = [[UIButton alloc]init];
btnName.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, imgPic.frame.origin.y+imgPic.frame.size.height+10.0, self.frame.size.width, 20.0);
btnName.center = CGPointMake(cell.contentView.center.x, imgPic.frame.origin.y+imgPic.frame.size.height+10.0);
btnName.titleLabel.text = [@"Nitin" uppercaseString];
//[btnName setTitle:[@"Nitin" uppercaseString] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.contentView addSubview:btnName];
```

Comment: try with setting `BackgroundColor` of your UIButton and check is it `visible` or not in `Cell`.?

Comment: Try creating button object like this `UIButton *btnName = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

Comment: @AbhishekSharma : I set the backgroud color to blue and button is appearing. But not text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution :

```
UIButton *btnName = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

also use

```
[btnName setTitle:[@"Nitin" uppercaseString] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

instead.

Please see [**Christien's**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652198/programmatically-change-title-of-uibutton-whose-title-was-set-in-ib-as-attribute) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could be something to do with adding the button to cell. Try setting its colour to blue or red to check if its visible at all. Also check if the final width and height of the button's frame is non-zero and its coordinates are inside the cell.