# iOS: Can I change color part of a Button Tittle?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am new in iOS. I want to know how can I change the color for each part of `UIButton` title.

For example, a part of title in my `UIButton` is **black** and another the part of title in my `UIButton` is **yellow**

This is the describe image
[image: Here is the button that I want]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: no, I can not found any tutorial for this but I can do it in Android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically change title of UIButton whose title was set in IB as attributed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652198/programmatically-change-title-of-uibutton-whose-title-was-set-in-ib-as-attribute)

Comment: @JasonNam please see my edit post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can use `NSMutableAttributedString` then add it to button with `[button setAttributedTitle:attString forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

To change color of a range in the Attribute String, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501808/uilabel-with-text-of-two-different-colors), basically its just 1 of the attribute dictionary

Read this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756067/ios-nsattributedstring-on-uibutton)

Comment: can you explains more, in the link you give me it . it does not talk about change color.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my question by using the code below.
For `UILabel`

```
NSMutableAttributedString *text =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
 initWithAttributedString: self.lblFriendBand.attributedText];

[text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
             value:[UIColor redColor]
             range:NSMakeRange(1, 2)];
[self.lblFriendBand setAttributedText: text];
```

For `UIButton`

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *text2 =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
         initWithAttributedString: self.btnFriendName.titleLabel.attributedText];
    [text2 addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                 value:[UIColor redColor]
                 range:NSMakeRange(1, 2)];
    [self.btnFriendName setAttributedTitle:text2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```